# Icefaces / JSF page does not update <TITLE>

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jboss, icefaces

When navigating from one page to another the  doesn't update in my pages.
Can anyone tell me why?

The setup:

Page a.xhtml:

```
<html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
    <h:head>
    <ui:insert name="stuffToInclude">
    </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    ....
    </h:body>
```

Page b.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

<ui:composition template="/a.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="stuffToInclude">
        <meta name="description" content="pierre" />
        <title>
            <ui:insert name="title"/>
        </title>
    </ui:define>

    </h:head>
```

Page c.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="/b.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
       <ice:outputText id="title" nospan="true" value="C Title" />
    </ui:define>
        .....
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Navigation to page c.jsf is done this way:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setViewId("c.xhtml");
```

The problem is that the "TITLE" element does not update to the new title. It keeps the value from the first page that I was on before going to c.xhtml.
It seems that the whole "HEAD" element isn't loaded for the new page.
Suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have now change the way we navigate to pages.
Now we're using:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(getViewId());
```